# Why do these accidentals exist?

Tags: piano, sheet-music, accidentals

I just bought a piano music book to start playing and learning again.

It was my understanding that accidentals only affect notes of the bar that they exist in. And because of that this bass clef really threw me off.

The piece is in the key of G and this bar (the second bar in the photo) has accidentals for E natural and F sharp.

[image]

Are they there because of the notes in the previous bar? Even though…

1. They’re in the previous bar.
2. They’re an octave away from the notes in this bar.

It stopped me for a couple minutes while I tried to work out what the notes were as I thought it was telling me to play F natural and G sharp.

(I’ve never been good at the bottom of the bass clef)

Comment: If the piece is in the key of G major, the E natural and F sharp in the second bar are cautionary accidentals (that could be put between brackets): they are not necessary but put for clarity, to highlight that the E-F in the second bar do not have the same accidentals as the E-F in the first bar.